# Why does GridView Rowupdating event not capture the new values of textbox?

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using a gridview. When I click on the edit button the update and cancel button appear.
Upon modifying the values in textbox which come from EditItemTemplate , the new values dont show in the event handler rowupdating(), instead I get the values which appear when the page was rendered. How do I grab the new values from these textboxes and proceed further?
Here is the code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>


    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cpuname") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cpuname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate> 
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
     </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>


</asp:GridView>


protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox text = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName");
        }
```

Comment: if(!IsPostBack) BindDataGrid() works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the two way binding here.  I.e.  Bind instead of Eval:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the link to documentation:

[Data-Binding Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

Here is my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Data");
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { i });
        GridView1.DataSource = table;
    if(!IsPostBack)  // <<<<<<<<<<<<
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }       

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox text = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtId");
    }
```

Comment: Nope. I tried this. It doesnt help. I am still getting the values which were rendered and not modified values

Comment: .Net 4. :).....I have tried a lot and I am stuck like for around 12 hrs now. I wonder what is wrong. Just toooo curious to know what exactly am I doing wrong

Comment: I think because you call the Bind at every Page_Load.  This should be done only once.  Check my code I posted, it works fine here.  Also, the Bind expression should be used.

Comment: @platon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1320/discussion-between-chandan-khatwani-and-platon)

Comment: even i m getting the same issue..
Edit : Did any of you guys figure out the problem.?

Answer (score 1):

If you have written the code to bind the grid in page load ensure that it is enclosed in `if(!IsPostBack)`
I hope it does help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`TextBox text = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.EditIndex].FindControl("txtName");`

Comment: That gives the old value, not the updating one during the rowupdating event

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me.

```
protected void MyGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string value = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That gives the old value, not the updating one during the rowupdating event

Answer (score -1):

i'm follow platon and it's work!

Put `if(!IsPostBack)` before `databind()`,
and insert `GridView1.DataBind();` after `GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;` in `GridView1_RowEditing`