# AJAX GridView RowUpdated event Not taking New column Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am doing Update operation  On Grid ... inside AJAX Update Panel . It doesnt fetch Column Data...The (!IsPostBack) Stuff doesnt seem to get working at all...

This is Grid Mark Up

```
          <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="List.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._3_Tier.List" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial, Trebuchet Ms;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        .style3
        {
            width: 182px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function x() {
            var firstName = document.getElementById("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID%>").value.trim();
            var lastName = document.getElementById("<%=txtLastName.ClientID%>").value.trim();
            var Age = document.getElementById("<%=txtAge.ClientID%>").value.trim();

            if (firstName == "") {
                alert('firstName cannot be null')
                return false;
            }


            if (lastName == "") {
                alert('lastName cannot be null')
                return false;
            }

            if (Age == "") {
                alert('Age cannot be null')
                return false;
            }

            return true;

        }
    </script>
    <title>List Records</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Demo: 3-Tier Architecture</h3>
    <div>
        <form id="form11" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="Server" ForeColor="red" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
                            DataKeyNames="Id" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowEditing="EditRecord"
                            OnRowUpdating="UpdateRecord" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelRecord" OnRowDeleting="DeleteRecord"
                            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="ChangePage"
                            OnSorting="SortRecords">
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2ff1BF" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" Width="75px" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("LastName") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%# Eval("Age") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Age") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete?')">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnBD" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </span>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        &nbsp;
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" OnRowUpdating="UpdateRecord1" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" Width="75px" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <br />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="Server" ForeColor="red" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
                                <table style="border: 2px solid #cccccc;">
                                    <tr style="background-color: #507CD1; color: White;">
                                        <th colspan="2">
                                            Add Records
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            First Name:
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Last Name:
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            Age:
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="Server" Columns="4"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="AddRecords" OnClientClick="if (!x()) { return false; }" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is Code Behind for Update Operation :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using BLL;

namespace WebApplication1._3_Tier
{
    public partial class List : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                BindGrid();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when Cancel button is clicked
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void CancelRecord(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            BindGrid();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Fires when Edit button is clicked
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void EditRecord(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindGrid();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires when Update button is clicked
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void UpdateRecord(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            int personID = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            int intResult = 0;
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            TextBox tFN = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFName");
            TextBox tLN = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtLName");
            TextBox tAge = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAge");

            // instantiate BAL
            PersonBAL3 pBAL = new PersonBAL3();

            try
            {
                intResult = pBAL.Update(personID, tFN.Text, tLN.Text, int.Parse(tAge.Text));
                if (intResult > 0)
                    lblMessage.Text = "Record Updated Successfully.";
                else
                    lblMessage.Text = "Record couldn't updated";
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ee.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                pBAL = null;
            }

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            // Refresh the list
            BindGrid();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// fires when Delete button is clicked
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int personID = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());


            // instantiate BAL
            PersonBAL3 pBAL = new PersonBAL3();
            try
            {
                pBAL.Delete(personID);

                lblMessage.Text = "Record Deleted Successfully.";
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ee.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                pBAL = null;
            }

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            // Refresh the list
            BindGrid();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires when page links are clicked
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void ChangePage(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            // Refresh the list
            BindGrid();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires when Columns heading are clicked
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void SortRecords(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = GridDataSource();

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

                dataView.Sort = GetSortExpression(e);

                GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Bind the gridview
        /// </summary>
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = GridDataSource();
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get GridView DataSource
        /// </summary>
        private DataTable GridDataSource()
        {
            PersonBAL3 p = new PersonBAL3();
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dTable = p.Load();
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ee.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                p = null;
            }

            return dTable;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get sort expression for the gridview
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetSortExpression(GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            string sortDirection = string.Empty;
            // if clicked on the same column twice then let it toggle the sort order, else reset to ascending
            if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
            {
                if (!ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString().Equals(e.SortExpression.ToLower()))
                {
                    ViewState["SortDirection"] = null;
                }
            }

            if (ViewState["SortDirection"] != null)
            {
                if (ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString().Equals("ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                    ViewState["SortDirection"] = "DESC";
                }
                else
                {
                    sortDirection = "ASC";
                    ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["SortDirection"] = "ASC";
            }
            ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression.ToLower();

            return e.SortExpression + " " + sortDirection;
        }
        #endregion Private Methods

        protected void AddRecords(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            string lastName = txtLastName.Text;
            int age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
            string lbl = lblMessage.Text;

            //Lets validate the page first
            if (!Page.IsValid)
                return;

            int intResult = 0;
            // Page is valid, lets go ahead and insert records
            // Instantiate BAL object
            PersonBAL3 pBAL = new PersonBAL3();
            // Instantiate the object we have to deal with
            try
            {
                int i;
                pBAL.Insert(firstName, lastName, age, out i);
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    lbl = "New record inserted successfully.";
                    BindGrid();
                }
                else
                    lbl = "FirstName [<b>" + firstName + "</b>] alredy exists, try another name";

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                lbl = ee.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                pBAL = null;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Problem is in this Line ;

```
 string firstName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFName").Text;
```

tFN.Text doesnt show data . I am getting datakey , textbox value from the findControl method . Just Text property is Blank

I Tried this :

```
((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[iCellIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

and this

```
string firstName = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
```

Not working ..

I tried suggestion from All the Posts Below :

[Why does GridView Rowupdating event not capture the new values of textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650968/why-does-gridview-rowupdating-event-not-capture-the-new-values-of-textbox?rq=1)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/627481/fetching-textbox-values-to-gridview-by-clicking-bu

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/346619/how-to-get-value-from-gridview-column-to-textbox

[Get TextBox value from GridView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863776/get-textbox-value-from-gridview-cell)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/156938/How-to-get-value-from-gridview-into-textbox

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/346619/how-to-get-value-from-gridview-column-to-textbox

http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-3-5-basics/78346-cant-get-value-textbox-gridview.html

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/346619/how-to-get-value-from-gridview-column-to-textbox

I even regenerated the Code .. Created the New Grid and everything . Still the Same Error

...Please suggest

Comment: Check your `Page_Load` event, you might be binding the `GridView1`. If so make sure you are binding `GridView1` only when it is not `PostBack`.

Comment: Yes I am Binding GridView if not postBack .. I Edited My Code Behind

Comment: Are you now getting `TextBox` value? or still enpty?

Comment: This Code was already present . I am still getting empty value

Answer (score 0):

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    TextBox tname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFName");
    string firstName =tname.Text;

     Or
    string firstName = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFName")).Text;
```

Comment: It display Index out of range Error . I tried to change it to string firstName =((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text; still error is same

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you ID as your datakeynames to update particular ID

.cs file

```
string id = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ID"].ToString();
TextBox FirstName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFName") as TextBox;
```

And .aspx page

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
    <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" Width="75px" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>                            
    </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**This will work unless or until u make your FirstName text empty before using update button**

Comment: I add your Code .. still Textbox text Property is empty .

Comment: Actually No error . Just "Text" property value is empty

Comment: then you text is empty before update command make sure your textbox is not null before updating

Comment: Script is in AJAX Update Panel..Does it make any Difference ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51897/discussion-between-user3487944-and-amitesh)